# Meteor email sending buggy when sending multiple emails in a short time

Tags: email, meteor

Quite new to Meteor.

I am sending an email when a user presses a button. I get these errors when I press the button:

```
I20170801-10:37:06.225(8)? Exception in defer callback: Error: Mail command failed: 503 5.5.2 Sender already specified [KL1PR03MB1416.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com]
I20170801-10:37:06.226(8)?     at Object.Future.wait (/Users/duminda/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.1bvf0xf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
I20170801-10:37:06.226(8)?     at SMTPConnection._syncSend (packages/meteor.js:213:24)
I20170801-10:37:06.226(8)?     at smtpSend (packages/email.js:112:8)
I20170801-10:37:06.227(8)?     at Object.Email.send (packages/email.js:208:5)
I20170801-10:37:06.227(8)?     at server/Travel/methods.js:5:19
I20170801-10:37:06.228(8)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1122:17)
I20170801-10:37:06.228(8)?     at packages/meteor.js:445:45
I20170801-10:37:06.229(8)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor.js:1176:24)
I20170801-10:37:06.229(8)?     - - - - -
I20170801-10:37:06.230(8)?     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/Users/duminda/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.0.cuwbi8++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:528:15)
I20170801-10:37:06.230(8)?     at SMTPConnection._actionMAIL (/Users/duminda/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.0.cuwbi8++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:1252:30)
I20170801-10:37:06.230(8)?     at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/duminda/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.0.cuwbi8++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:759:14)
I20170801-10:37:06.231(8)?     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/Users/duminda/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.0.cuwbi8++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:669:16)
I20170801-10:37:06.231(8)?     at SMTPConnection._onData (/Users/duminda/.meteor/packages/email/.1.2.0.cuwbi8++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:493:10)
I20170801-10:37:06.231(8)?     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
I20170801-10:37:06.232(8)?     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
I20170801-10:37:06.232(8)?     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
I20170801-10:37:06.232(8)?     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
I20170801-10:37:06.233(8)?     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:537:20)
```

My code:

```
    if(response === 1) {
        sendDeferredEmail({
                to: email,
                from: "smtp@***.com",
                subject: "New Travel Request pending response by " + user.username,
                html: user.username + " added a new travel request." + "<br>"
            });
...



function sendDeferredEmail(params)
{
    try {
        Meteor.defer(function () {
            Email.send({to: params.to, from: params.from, subject: params.subject, html: params.html});
        });
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log("Caught exception when sending email:\n" + e);
    }
}
```

The email setup:

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://smtp@***:587';
```

What is going wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment but lack reputation... How fast are you pressing the buttons? Most online mail servers don't allow relay sends to avoid users spamming. Have you tried setting this as a server side function and using `Meteor.call()` to trigger an `Email.send()`?

Comment: Quite fast.
I added a method and used `Meteor.call()`, still the same result.

Is there a way to queue the email sends to get around any limitations of the mail server?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how fast the email server responds (are you using to mailgun to send?) but you could store the email parameters, set a function to loop through that array with a delay and that should do it. Probably not the prettiest way but I think it would work.